# How to upgrade vehicles in Protoype?

Tags: prototype

Anyone knows how we can upgrade the vehicles in Prototype? You can see something like 0/1 and it says "consume the commander". What commander? I must have consumed 100s of people by now. I can't get to upgrade it through the upgrade screen.

(I'm right now rescuing Dana with an armored tank)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Go to a base, indicated by a blue shield icon at the center of a blue area on your minimap.
- Consume the captain (the guy wearing a cap and sunglasses)
- Enter the base via the yellow area in front of the base door.
- Look for the soldier with this icon above his head:

  [image: upgrade icon]
- Consume him
- You can watch the process in this youtube video: